# Filter for Time Zone ignored in controller and view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, timezone

I defined a method in my ApplicationController that looks like such:

```
def use_time_zone(&block)
  Time.use_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)', &block)
end
```

I then used,

```
around_filter: use_time_zone
```

to ensure that the method was applied to all times across the entire application.  Despite my method and filter when I print

```
<%= Time.now %> <%= Date.today %>
```

in any view it prints the time value in the improper time zone.  I read recently in the API documentation that around_filter: has been deprecated, if this is true what is now used in its place?

Answer (score 0):

You can define Time zone in config of your application

```
config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
# or
# config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
```

Comment: I want to be able to configure the Time Zone per user so I didn't place the logic in the config of my application, sorry I should have specified that prior